# Git - commit and tag in a single command

Tags: git, git-commit, git-tag

I am doing a commit in a git in a following manner:

```
git commit -m "message"
```

And then I am adding a tag

```
git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02
```

Is it possible to do this in a single command?

Comment: It's not possible in a single *Git* command, but many Git commands themselves are made up of other Git commands. For instance, `git pull` used to be a shell script that ran `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. The script got fancier and slower and eventually the Git guys rewrote it in C because Windows is so awful. But you can just write your own command that runs the two Git commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a commitag.bat file, put it in one of the system PATH folder.

```
git commit -m %1  
git tag -a %2
```

run`commitag "message" v1.2`

Comment: You cannot get commit id `9fceb02` without committing first. So between `git commit` and `git tag` there have to be a command to get the hash.

Comment: @phd Yes, you are right. If you want to tag the latest commit, the 3rd argument is not required.